# Matrix of values generated randomly with Univariate Distribution

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to understand an observation made in a research paper. Before i write down the observation i want to put the context to avoid any confusion. The observation is about a matrix of values and in that matrix the values, which are somehow related to each other, need to be grouped together and form a new sub matrix. Here is the observation.

*Given the input matrix $ A= \{ a_{ij} \} $ where $i$ stands for rows and $j$ stands for columns, consider counting the number of rows with the property that the value in column $p$ is smaller than the value in column $q$ i.e. $\#\{k: a_{kp} < a_{kq}\}$ . If the values in the dataset are generated randomly with univariate distribution, half of the rows on average are expected to have this property and half are not. Addition of another column $r$ to the series, such that values in this column $r$ are larger than the values in column q i.e $\#\{k: a_{kp} < a_{kq} < a_{kr}\}$ should result in another reduction of number of rows by half . Thus, addition of the column to the series reduces the number of concordant rows by half*

Now my first question arises here, Do i need to iterate over $i$ and $j$ to select $p$ and $q$. What strategy is being used here to select the values of $p$ and $q$. Secondly can you give me a square matrix of $8$x$8$ that has univariate distribution and i can apply both of the said property. Lets continue the observation.

*On the other hand is the distribution of the data is not uniform and there exists a monotonic relationships between rows in some subsets of conditions any addition of the pattern specific column wont eliminate the rows belonging to this pattern.*

Now what kind of monotonic relationship will yield this type of property. Is there matrix that helps to understand this. Wasnt the property $\#\{k: a_{kp} < a_{kq} < a_{kr}\}$ had some sort of relationship too.

I know thats a bit long post but i really need to understand this observation for the thesis defense. This paragraph is taken from the paper named as **EBIC: An evolutionary based parellel biclustering algorithm for pattern discovery**

Answer (score 1):

What that paragraph is saying is "suppose we have the matrix, and pick *any* two indices $p$ and $q$." So maybe it's a $12 \times 12$ matrix, and I look at $p = 4$ and $q = 7$.

Now walk through the rows, one at a time. Is $a_{13} < a_{17}$? The answer's either "yes" or "no". Is $a_{23} < a_{27}$? Again, yes or no. When you're done counting up, you'll find some number of rows produced a "yes" answer --- maybe five of them. In that case, $\#\{k : a_{kp} < a_{kq} \}$ is five. But on average, given the uniform distribution of the $a_{ij}$, you'd expect it to be six. Maybe for some other $pq$ pair, you'd get seven. But the *average* number of rows with this property, for a fixed $p,q$ pair, should be six.

The statement following this one, "Addition of another column $$ to the series, such that values in this columns are larger than the values in column $q$ ..." doesn't seem entirely obvious to me; the numbers in column $r$ don't have to be larger than those in some random position, but rather must be larger than those in column $q$, which is already supposed to be larger than column $p$, so we could have to compute this as a conditional probability, and I have my doubts about the glibness of the assertion that we lose a factor of two...but I could easily be wrong. I haven't even had a cup of tea yet this morning.

The "On the other hand..." sentence doesn't really make sense to me, because it talks about "conditions", which might index rows or columns, which I can't discern without reading more of the paper.

---

I wanted to check my suspicions about the conditional probability, so I wrote some matlab code:

```
function trand()
trials = 2000;
u = zeros(trials, 1);
v = zeros(trials, 1);
for s = 1:trials
  N = 24;
  a = rand(N);
  p = 1; q = 2; r = 3;
  v(s) = sum( a(:, p) < a(:, q));
  u(s) = sum( (a(:, p) < a(:, q)) & (a(:,q) < a(:,r)));
end
mean(v)
mean(u)
```

When I ran this code, I got that the average number of rows of my $12 \times 12$ matrix for which the $p$th entry is less than the $q$th was $12.0195$, as expected and claimed in the paper. (That was `mean(v)` in the program.) When I tried adding in the $r$th column, I got `mean(u)` turning out to be $4.0280$, which is a long way from the $6$ that the authors seem to be predicting.

Frankly, either I'm misreading what they're claiming, or they're just plain wrong.

---

Actually, after a few more minutes of thinking, I'm pretty sure they're wrong. For in picking the indices $p, q, r$, I could have made any one of six choices of order; each of those six choices of order should result in the same expected number of rows. But that means that the expected number of "good" rows for any one choice should by $1/6$th of the total number of rows, i.e., $4$, which my numerical experiments confirm, and not $6$.

Comment: i am sorry , i found a typo in my post that that column $r$ needs to be greater than the column $q$.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what my code tested. (I've also renamed the variables to $p,q,r$ so that they match the text's description...sorry about the confusion in the first version.)

Comment: When i was thinking on it, i thought that , maybe first we need to check the first condition that $p$ is less than $q$ and remove the rows. After that , the resultant mstrix will be halved . Now again we need to bring some column $r$ such that its values are greater than $q$ and again evaluate the previous resultant matrix .. maybe this way , we will again be able yo halved the matrix

Comment: Well...that might all be true (I don't think so), but it's not what that paragraph says.

Comment: if thats confusing let me try to put in other words . initially, say we have a matrix of 12x12 and we evaluate the whether p is less than q. now by removing the rows that satify the condition , we might get a matrix 6x12.. Now again add a column r whose values are greater than the column q and our matrix becomes 6x13. Now after evaluating the condition we might halved the matix with respect to number to rows i.e 3x13. Does it make sense ..

Comment: well still i will upvote your answer .. you have helped me alot. however did you make the matrix with univariate distribution ..

Comment: I made it with a uniform distribution on the interval $[0, 1]$...but it would produce the same results for any other distribution. For instance, by changing "rand" to "randn", you get the normal distribution ; I get 11.9855 and 3.9905 as the answers for a run in that case. I also raised each random number to the 4th power (which makes them cluster near 0), and still got 12.0369 and 4.0430.

Comment: Thanks for the insights , now i will look for the _on the other hand part_ :)

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of this paper. You are absolutely right, Asian, there is a glitch in the paper that makes this particular claim false. The rest of the paper is not impacted at all, as the fitness function could be defined in any way.

The correct version of this paragraph should be:

*Addition of another column  to the series, such that values in this column  are larger than the values in column q i.e $\#\{:_{}<_{}<_{}\}$ should result in another reduction of number of rows by **at least** half. Thus, the addition of the column to the series reduces the number of concordant rows by **at least** half.*

The actual value that describes this property (i.e. the number of rows that follow a particular monotonous order of length k) is the number of rows of the dataset divided by the factorial of k.

Comment: Well, Thanks for your time and clarification.

Comment: suppose i have applied ebic algorithm on a dataset and as a result i have 100 biclusters.  Now suppose i have a test sample and want to know to which bicluster from 1 to 100 does this test sample belong to. How will i say for sure that my test sample bekongs to nth bicluster out of 100 biclusters. What measures will tell me that the test sample belongs MOSTLY to nth bicluster

Comment: Biclusters are commonly defined as tuples of (Rows, Columns). It seems to me that you are using a biclustering algorithm, which is an unsupervised method, for classification, which is a supervised task. If this is the case, the most straightforward way of assigning a test cas to bicluster(s) is verification of its monotonicity against each of the biclusters (with regards to approximate and negatively correlated patterns) and assigning it to those meeting the monotonicity of the test case. It is up to your criteria to decide which bicluster is the most similar to considered test sample.

Comment: Hi @athril. Thank you for your help. I was learning some of foundations so that i can understand your algorithm. It took me a while to understand some of the things of evolutionary computing but still i lack some of the things. Now can you please help me about verifying the monotonicity. It would be helpful if you tell me where in your given code or paper you were calculating or describled how to calculate monotonicity for the genereated population of columns. Can you please guide what monotonicity rules you have applied. Maybe by having an example i will understand. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The monocity is checked on GPU-side, more specifically in `kernels/evaluate_trends.cu`. Two variables are used (each of size: 1 x num_rows): `trendvalue` - for storing the values of a given column of a bicluster, and `trendcheck` - for counting in each row the number of times the values of a bicluster are monotonous.  You could imagine this as a sliding window consisting of 1 column throughout column set of each of the biclusters.  The exact check is performed in  line 54. Both fitness calculation and bicluster extraction used this kernel.
Please e-mail me if you had any other question.